# Road distance calculation using latitudes and longitudes in excel/google sheets

Tags: vba, excel, latitude-longitude

I'm looking to get road distances between 2 addresses. I have the postcode and the latitude and longitudes of each address.

I have it laid out in a grid (see image attached), as there are 500 addresses that I need the distances between and can't figure out a better way to do it.

[image: see image attached]

The issue I have is I can't use the Haversine formula, as it's for mileage claims so needs to be road distances.

I am a noob regarding coding, and have been slowly teaching myself, but I need a way that it will look up each set and fill the relevant/corresponding box.

I'm aware of the google API stuff, but not really sure how it works, or how I'd go about implementing something like that into my scripts.

Comment: I have not tried it, so this is a genuine, not snarky question. Do you have a known road distance you can work with? I would test that against the Haversine formula and see if there is an appreciable difference.

Comment: You can only get an exact distance by using a navigation api such as OpenStreetMap or Google Maps/Here Maps/.. provide. If the distances between the cities are large enough, simple math (e.g. the Haversine formula) would give a very close approximation

Comment: There is a tutorial for everything: [Excel VBA - Calculate distance between two addresses or coordinates](https://analystcave.com/excel-calculate-distances-between-addresses/)

Comment: I would assume that some level of estimation is allowable by any reasonable employer.  If they're going to be double-checking it down to the mile, then ask the employer what their method is.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I guess it would have been nice if you could tack on x%, but you are telling me it is not predictable. I wasn't trying to argue with the OP, just wondering if the underlying assumption was correct. I said I did not know.

Comment: @JeremyKahan - Sry, didn't mean to sound snarky :) I wasn't sure how much of a difference it would be either until your comment prompted me to check. On a 100km straight-ish highway near me, the difference is 15%.

Comment: Wow, that is big. Thanks, no worries.

Comment: The employers method is getting me to manually type all the addresses into bing and work them out.

Comment: Hence my need to make this automated and save me hours worth of pointless data entry.
And allowing the teachers to just fill their schools in themselves without any calculation needed. (Forever trying to scam the system + half of them don't know how the internet works!)

Comment: Also, too small a distance to use the haversine method to aproximate. 
The furthest distance we have for a full trip (around 6 schools in one day) is 140 miles. the least is 0.4.

Answer (score 5):

The Google [**Distance Matrix API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) provides travel, distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations. The API returns information based on the recommended route between start and end points, as calculated by the Google Maps API, and consists of rows containing duration and distance values for each pair of points.

Google Maps' set of APIs used to allow several free calls per day but they recently changed their billing structure, so you'll need to set up a billing account. Here are the new prices for the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing#distance-matrix) (unless you've managed to get a free trial). Basically $5 to $10 USD for every 1,000 calls to the API.

There are several specific examples [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixRequests) of how to call the API via a web browser or programmatically.

---

### Use an Excel worksheet formula to create links

This will generates links to each trip's driving directions page in Google Maps (which includes distance) and will speed up the process (if you have at least basic knowledge of Excel).

1. **Enter your sets of coordinates** into an Excel worksheet, two coordinates sets per row in cells `A` to `D`, starting in row 2, in the order `Origin Latitude, Origin Longitude, Destination Latitude, Destination Longitude`. See image [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFoxa.png).
2. **Paste this formula** into cell `E2`:
   `=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/'" & A2 & "," &B2&"'/'" & C2 & "," &D2&"'/@"&AVERAGE(A2,C2)&","&AVERAGE(B2,D2) &",12z/")`
3. 'Fill down', or **copy/paste the formula**, so it's in all the rows with coordinates.
4. **Click each link** to load Google Maps for that trip, and manually make note of the driving distance for each coordinate set.
   (Note that each trip may have multiple options depending on which route you travelled.)

<sub>**Click images to enlarge.**</sub>

[image]

<sub>Result in browser:</sub>

[image]

With a decent Internet connection, I figure each one to take 10-15 seconds, so you're looking at around an hour total.

(I suggest breaking it up instead of trying to do them all at one.  Better yet, pay a kid, or get multiple children and make a game out of it...)

---

## Function using Google Maps API

I remembered a function I had stashed away that *appears* to still work for free... but based on the new pricing guidelines, I wouldn't be surprised if it only worked for a few calls a day (for "testing purposes").

1. This one take the origin & destination locations in two cells (instead of four), but is more flexible with how you enter the locations.  Example:

   [image: img]
2. In Excel, paste this code into a new (standard) module. <sub>([Here's how.](https://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html#videoreg))</sub>

```vb
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
'Returns Google Maps driving distance between two points in kilometres
    Dim url As String, html As String, regEx As Object, matches As Object
    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?" & _
        "origins=" & Replace(start, " ", "+") & "&destinations=" & _
        Replace(dest, " ", "+")
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .Send: html = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        regEx.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regEx.Global = False
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(html)
        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            GetDistance = CDbl(Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", _
                Application.International(xlListSeparator))) / 1000
        Else: GetDistance = -1: End If 'there was a problem.
    End With
End Function
```

3. With the example in the above image, you'd enter in cell `C2`:

   ```vb
   =GetDistance(A2,B2)
   ```

...to get the driving distance in kilometres.

---

## Haversine Method

For the sake of completeness, I'll include the [Haversine Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) which calculates a "straight line" distance mathematically (with no API calls).

**This is *not* driving distance.** In my test of a relatively straight distance between towns, this method was different by about 15%, however, this is suitable (and faster) for other "non-driving related" purposes.

### **Excel:**

```vb
Public Function Distance(lat1 As Double, lon1 As Double, _
        lat2 As Double, lon2 As Double) As Double
'Excel: Returns kilometers distance in a straight line (Haversine)
    On Error GoTo dErr
    Dim dist As Double, theta As Double: theta = lon1 - lon2
    dist = Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + _
        Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * _
        Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta))
    dist = rad2deg(WorksheetFunction.Acos(dist))
    Distance = dist * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
    Exit Function
dErr:
    Distance = -1
End Function
Function deg2rad(ByVal deg As Double) As Double
    deg2rad = (deg * WorksheetFunction.Pi / 180#)
End Function
Function rad2deg(ByVal rad As Double) As Double
    rad2deg = rad / WorksheetFunction.Pi * 180#
End Function
```

### MS Access:

Access is slightly different due to the lack of Excel's math functions, so I might as well include it:

```vb
Const pi = 3.14159265358979
Public Function Distance(lat1 As Double, lon1 As Double, lat2 As Double, lon2 As Double) As Double
'MS Access: Returns kilometres distance in a straight line  Haversine)
    Dim dist As Double, theta As Double: theta = lon1 - lon2
    dist = Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Cos(deg2rad(theta))
    Distance = rad2deg(ACos(dist)) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
End Function
Function ACos(N As Double) As Double: ACos = pi / 2 - ASin(N): End Function
Function deg2rad(ByVal deg As Double) As Double: deg2rad = (deg * pi / 180#): End Function
Function rad2deg(ByVal rad As Double) As Double: rad2deg = rad / pi * 180#: End Function
Public Function ASin(N As Double) As Double: ASin = 2 * Atn(N / (1 + Sqr(1 - (N * N)))): End Function
```

[image]
<sup>Spherical triangle solved by the [Law of Haversines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#The_law_of_haversines)</sup>

Comment: If you are gonna go the whole  on straight line you should probably put your crow through Vicenty's formula. +1.  Imagine this is a crow for testing purposes==> 

Answer (score -1):

I would do it with arcgis:
You plot the two points
You should have some road shapefile that contains the road you want to calculate the distance the you clip seeing the points, then you measure that clipped polilyne